# Acessar objeto palavra composta, $.each, Javascript?

Tags: javascript

tenho um problema em acessar um objeto que tem espaço em branco no nome.

usei json encode no php e obtenho a resposta assim do ajax:

```
{Seguranca: 0, Saude Publica: 4, Transportes: 0, Outros: 0, Urbanizacao: 0, …}
```

utilizo each para iterar:

```
$.each(pontos, function(index, ponto) {}
```

**como acesso o *Saude Publica* ?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para aceder a propriedades com espaços podes usar `['nome da propriedade']`.

<strike>Mas o problema aqui é outro. Não podes usar o `$.each` sozinho, tens de usar `Object.keys`.</strike>

Na verdade o `$.each` aceita e itera objetos. Mas nesse caso a API da callback é `(nomeDaPropriedade, valor)`

Assim corrigido será:

```js
    var objeto = {
      'Seguranca': 0,
      'Saude Publica': 4,
      'Transportes': 0,
      'Outros': 0,
      'Urbanizacao': 0
    };

    $.each(objeto, (chave, valor) => {
      console.log(chave, valor);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Ou em javaScript nativo:

```js
var objeto = {
  'Seguranca': 0,
  'Saude Publica': 4,
  'Transportes': 0,
  'Outros': 0,
  'Urbanizacao': 0
};

Object.keys(objeto).forEach((chave) => {
  const valor = objeto[chave];
  console.log(chave, valor);
});
```

Comment: valeu guerreiro!

Comment: @AbnerPassosMagalhaes na verdade tinha um erro na resposta... corrigi.